# Error con una tupla

Tags: python

```
def imprimir_nombres(personas):
  for x in range(len(personas)):
     print(f"Persona {x}: {personas[x[1]]}")

personas = [
   ('Martin', 'Soto', (24, 8, 1990), ),
   ('Gabriel', 'Cuellar', (2, 6, 1974)),
   ('Humberto', 'Espinosa', (14, 11, 1973))]
imprimir_nombres(personas)
```

El problema que tengo es que quiero printar solo la posicion 1, de tal manera que queadria asi:
Martin
Gabriel
Humberto

Per me da el error: "TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable" y nose como arreglarlo.
Agradezco cualquier ayuda :)

Comment: Tu for, `range(len(personas))` estas interactuando en numeros, y tu tupla son nombres. Mejor hazlo simplemente con `for persona in personas` de esa forma vas elemento por elemento, y los indices los asigna python

Answer (score 0):

Tienes una lista de tuplas. Cuando haces lo siguiente estas queriendo decir que x es un tipo de lista, lo cual no es, por eso el error. x es un entero que usas para recorrer cada posicion de la lista.

```
print(f"Persona {x}: {personas[x[1]]}")
```

Tu lista es personas, personas en la posicion x te regresará una tupla. Cambia a lo siguente para obtener el nombre.

```
personas[x][0]
```

Answer (score -1):

Esta es la solución para conseguir el resultado que tu quieres:

```
def imprimir_nombres(personas):
    p=''
    for x in range(len(personas)):
        p+=' '+personas[x][0]
        # print(f"Persona {x}: {personas[x][0]}")
    print (p)

personas = [
    ('Martin', 'Soto', (24, 8, 1990), ),
    ('Gabriel', 'Cuellar', (2, 6, 1974)),
    ('Humberto', 'Espinosa', (14, 11, 1973))]
imprimir_nombres(personas)
```

La diferencia está en cómo se usan los corchetes para leer los datos de la persona: `personas[x][0]` (en lugar de `personas[x[1]]`)